# get_all_by date range not working in Jamie Rumbelow's MY_Model for CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter-2

I cannot get a date range to work with Jamie Rumbelow's MY_Model. Here is my code:

```
$data['customers'] = $this->customerrecord_model->get_many_by('timestamp BETWEEN "'. date('Y-m-d', strtotime('First day of last month')). '" and "'. date('Y-m-d', strtotime('Last day of last month')).'"');
```

This query runs but returns 0 results (there are several entries in the database that should be returned)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

OK, this is kickself. Issue was not with the query but

```
 strtotime('Last day of last month')
```

which was returning **first** day of last 
month - so the range was nil.

Simple echo statement diagnosed. Doh!